# Visual Studio 2008 JavaScript behaving different than live site

Tags: onload-event

I have several iis applications with a window.onload() defined which work properly when running directly from the web server.  When I try to debug the same project on new  machine with IE 10, it is behaving completely differently.  Is there a configuration change that needs to be made within VS 2008.

Here is what I see.

1. When function window.onlad(){//code//} is defined. it does not fire in design mode.
2. When the function is defined as: function windowOnLoad(){//code//}, it needs to be called from a different line.
3. When the function fires as defined in the previous point, it runs before the rest of the body tag has rendered and therefore any calls to get form controls objects fails because it's not there yet.

I am surprised at this behavior because it is unique to running in the development environment alone.  The live application works fine as defined in point number 1.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Please help

Comment: Javascript runs on the browser. I would recommend you debug your javascript using a browser debugging tool and not visual studio.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  Before upgrading to IE 10 this was not an issue.  All of a sudden JavaScript interpreter/debugger within visual studio is behaving differently than IE 10.  I am wondering if there is a setting that needs to be changed within VS.

Comment: Just an update.  I rolled back the Internet explorer version to IE 9 and it all started to work.  Go figure?

Comment: I still think it is browser related. I think you are finding that.